# Conditional On custom field plugin metabox

Tags: php, custom-field, functions

I've trying to run a conditional on the custom field I made with the Custom Fields plugin, I made a true and false check box.

I just need to check if the box is true or false really. I've tried something like this but the word hello appears even when the

```
<?php
    $premium = get_field('premium');
    if ( !isset($premium)) {
        echo 'hello';
    }
?>
```

Basically I've trying to change the page layout if this is ticked. I'm sure this is quite easy.

Thanks for any input

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can't work because `isset()` returns true if there is a value, `true`and `false` are values, ergo it won't work. Do it like this instead:

```
$premium = get_field('premium');
if ( ! $premium ) { // this is basically short for $premium == false
    echo 'not premium';
}
```

Comment: Aww thanks Ialocin again!, I was at the understanding ! had to have either empty or isset with it. This should work for what I'm wanting now then. Least I'm getting slightly closer to the awnser each time haha!.

Comment: It really seems like I'm always there, when you're asking your questions. BTW for getting such things straight it's always good to know your [PHP Manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/index.php). @dannyw24

Comment: I've just ran this on my site Ialocin, Tried ticking the box and unticking it always outputs not premium. If I'm correct when its not ticked it should output 'not premium' - Believe I had the field name wrong therefore it was always false. Just changed this now to ('premium_stock_supplier')

Comment: Have you debugged what the actual values in your field are? @dannyw24

Comment: Marked this correct now @ialocin. Thanks again for the help.